# How do I split multiple columns into rows by delimiter in Power BI?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, powerbi

I have following table structure imported to Microsoft Power BI:

[image]

How do I split columns `ItemID` and `Quantity` so that the values separated by comma will correspond, e.g.

[image]

The table is stored in Google BigQuery database, so if my problem can be solved via (standard) SQL query, I'll be happy to know that, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT '1' TransactionID, '1,2,3' ItemID, '1,1,1' Quantity, 6500 revenue UNION ALL
  SELECT '2', '1,3', '1,2', 4000 UNION ALL
  SELECT '3', '1,2', '', 3000 
)
SELECT TransactionID, ItemID, Quantity, revenue
FROM `project.dataset.table`, 
UNNEST(SPLIT(ItemId)) AS ItemID WITH OFFSET pos1,
UNNEST(SPLIT(Quantity)) AS Quantity WITH OFFSET pos2
WHERE pos1 = pos2 OR Quantity = ''
ORDER BY TransactionID
```

with output as

```sql
TransactionID   ItemID  Quantity    revenue  
1               1       1           6500     
1               2       1           6500     
1               3       1           6500     
2               1       1           4000     
2               3       2           4000     
3               1                   3000     
3               2                   3000
```

Just a direction as you need to adjust this to handle case for example when number of items does not correspond to number of quantities, etc.

For example, something like below

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT '1' TransactionID, '1,2,3' ItemID, '1,11,111' Quantity, 6500 revenue UNION ALL
  SELECT '2', '1,3', '1111', 4000 UNION ALL
  SELECT '3', '1,2', '', 3000 
)
SELECT 
  TransactionID, ItemID,
  IFNULL((SELECT q
    FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(Quantity)) AS q WITH OFFSET pos2 
    WHERE pos2 = pos
  ), '') Quantity,
  revenue
FROM (
  SELECT TransactionID, ItemID, Quantity, revenue , pos
  FROM `project.dataset.table`, 
  UNNEST(SPLIT(ItemId)) AS ItemID WITH OFFSET pos
)
ORDER BY TransactionID, pos
```

Comment: Currently, there is either corresponding number of items or no info in quantity, so your solution fits perfectly. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If your happy with a SQL answer then PIVOT TABLES are the way to go.

They are a great way to convert rows to columns, and far less messy than doing multiple joins to the same table.

I won't post a full version here as it's well documented, once you know what to search for.

Good luck.